# Row selection and pagination - Vue

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, pagination, storage

Using vue, I display my database in a table.
My table contains a lot of rows. Therefore, I use pagination. 
Using the select function, I can select multiple rows and store them in an array.

The problem:

- I select some rows in my table. The data from the row is stored in my array called selected. I let them appear next to my table.
  Using pagination, I go to the next page. My data is still stored in this array. When I now select another row. My array is emptied, 
  my data from my section is gone.

How can I solve this? Why does this happen? Is there a way to store this data so it isn't lost?
Did I miss something?

Bellow, you find my code. Thanks for the help.

## Vue code

```
   <!-- Main table -->
<b-row align-v="start">
    <b-col sm="8">
        <b-table class="col-sm-12"
            show-empty
            striped hover
            selectable
            stacked="md"
            :items="values"
            :fields="fields"
            :select-mode="selectMode"
            :current-page="currentPage"
            :filter="valueSearch"
            :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
            :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
            :sort-direction="sortDirection"
            @filtered="onFiltered"
            @row-selected="rowSelected"

            <template slot="name" slot-scope="row">
                {{row.item.name}}
            </template>
            <template slot="id" slot-scope="row">
                {{ row.item.id }}
            </template>
            <template slot="ref" slot-scope="row">
                {{row.item.ref}}
            </template>
            <template slot="specific" slot-scope="row">
                {{row.item.specific}}
            </template>
            <template slot="iso" slot-scope="row">
                {{row.item.iso}}
            </template>
            <template slot="tax" slot-scope="row">
                {{row.item.tax}}
            </template>
            <template slot="amount" slot-scope="row">
                <span class='dot largerSize' :class="statusColor[range(row.item.amount)]"></span>
            </template>
        </b-table>
    </b-col>
    <b-col sm="4">
        Here comes the value selected. 
        <div v-for="selectedvalue in selected" :key="selectedvalue.id">
            {{ selectedvalue.id }} - {{selectedvalue.name}}
            {{selected}}

        </div>
    </b-col>
</b-row>
 <!-- How is sorted? & Pagnation -->
<b-row align-v="end" class="mb-2">
    <b-col>
        Sorting By: <b>{{ sortBy | capitalize }}</b>, Sort Direction:
        <b>{{ sortDesc ? 'Descending' : 'Ascending' }}</b>
    </b-col>
    <b-col>
        <b-pagination v-model="currentPage" :total-rows="totalRows" :per-page="perPage" class="my-0"></b-pagination>
    </b-col>
    <b-col>One of three columns</b-col>
</b-row>
```

## Javascript

```
<script>   
export default {
    props: ['valuedata','minamount','maxamount'],
    data() {
        return {
            values: this.valuedata,
            statusColor: ["red","orange","green"],
            totalRows: 1,
            currentPage: 1,
            perPage: 10,
            pageOptions: [5, 10, 20, 50,100],
            sortBy: "id",
            sortDesc: false,
            sortDirection: 'asc',
            filter: null,
            selectMode: 'multi',
            fixed: true,
            selected: [],
          fields: {
                id: {
                    label: "Id",
                    sortable: true
                },
                name: {
                    label: "Name",
                    sortable: true
                },
                ref: {
                    label: "Ref",
                    sortable: true
                },
                iso: {
                    label: "Iso",
                    sortable: true
                },
                tax: {
                    label: "Tax",
                    sortable: true
                },
                specific: {
                    label: "specific",
                    sortable: true
                },
                amount: {
                    label: "amount",
                    sortable: true
                }                    
            }
        } 
    },
     computed:{ 
        hits: function(){
            var hits = this.values.length
            return hits
        }            
    },
    mounted () {
        this.totalRows = this.values.length

    },
     methods: {
        onFiltered(filteredItems) {
            // Trigger pagination to update the number of buttons/pages due to filtering
            this.totalRows = filteredItems.length
            this.currentPage = 1
        },
        // Option: enables the storage of selected rows
        rowSelected(items){
            console.log(items[0].name)
            this.selected = items
        },
        // Function: color code amount
        range: function(x){
            if (x < this.minamount){
                return 0;
            }else if(x >= this.minamount && x <= this.maxamount ){
                return 1;
            }else if(x >= this.maxamount ){
                return 2;
            }
        }
    },
    filters: {
        // Function: captitalize the first letter
        capitalize: function (value) {
            value = value.toString()
            return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1)
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, you replace all items in `selected` :

```
// Option: enables the storage of selected rows
rowSelected(items){
    console.log(items[0].name)
    this.selected = items
},
```

What you want to do is adding values, not replacing them, so IMHO what you should is something like :

```
// Option: enables the storage of selected rows
rowSelected(items){
    console.log(items[0].name)

    items.forEach(item => {
        const selectedIds = this.selected.map(selectedItem => selectedItem.id);

        // I guess you don't want twice the same item in your array
        if (!selectedIds.includes(item.id) {
           this.selected.push(item)
        }
    })
},
```